# angular ui-router parent url set to /

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Using ui-router and setting the parent state url to `/` results in my url looking like `localhost:8000/#//child` when looking at a child page. I'd like just a single `/` between the hash and child.

I tried leaving the parent state url blank, but then ui-sref won't link back to the parent state when using an anchor link. Anybody got a solution for having a root level un-named parent url?

**app.config**

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

$stateProvider
  .state("main", {
    url: "/",
    templateUrl: 'sites/main/main.html',
    controller : 'MainController',
    resolve: {
      items: function(srvMenu) {
          return srvMenu.getNav();
      }
  }

 })

});
```

**child.config**

```
emergency.config(function($stateProvider) { 
$stateProvider
    .state("main.emergency", {
      url: "/emergency",
      templateUrl: 'sites/emergency/emergency_menu.html',
      controller : 'EmenuController',
      resolve: {
          emenu: function(srvEmergency) {
              return srvEmergency.getMenu();
          }
      }

    })

    .state("main.emergency.detail", {
      url: "/detail",
      templateUrl: 'sites/emergency/emergency_detail.html',
    })
});
```

Comment: Can you post your app.config()? I've used the ui-router with the parent as / and have never seen this problem...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `ui-router` has solution *(almost)* for anything. There is a working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/02x1AU?p=preview). The feature we will se in action is called: [Absolute Routes (^)](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#absolute-routes-)

So, let's start with requirement, to have these URL routes:

```
domain/#/                             -- root for main
domain/#/emergency/                   -- main.emergency
domain/#/emergency/detail             -- main.emergency.detail
```

Which should be working when using this `ui-sref` state calls:

```
<ul>
    <li><a ui-sref="main">Main</a></li>
    <li><a ui-sref="main.emergency">Emergency</a></li>
    <li><a ui-sref="main.emergency.detail">Detail</a></li>
</ul>
```

Now, the trick is:

- the root *(first)* state must use `url: "/"`, to have some unique identification
- but the next state can start its definition from the root again: with this setting:
  `url: "^/..."`

Here is the state configuration, enabling the desired results

```
  $stateProvider
    // root with '/'
    .state("main", {
      url: "/",
      templateUrl: 'main.tpl.html',
    })
    // here we start again from the root '/emergency'
    .state("main.emergency", {
      url: "^/emergency",
      templateUrl: 'emergency_menu.tpl.html',
    })
    // parent and child '/emergency/detail
    .state("main.emergency.detail", {
      url: "/detail",
      templateUrl: 'emergency_detail.tpl.html',
    });
```

And here is the documentation:

#### [Absolute Routes (^)](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#absolute-routes-)

*...and the working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/02x1AU?p=preview)...*

Comment: Great to see that, `ui-router` is awesome tool ;)