# AngularJS - Nested states

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

When using nested states from [UI Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router), this will only work if you navigate the page through the nest. i.e.:

If I have

```
.state('home', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'home.html'
    ...
})
.state('home.page', {
    url: '/page',
    templateUrl: 'page.html'
    ...
})
.state('home.page.sub' , {
    url: '/page/sub',
    templateUrl: 'sub.html'
    ...
})
```

Now the problem is if I directly visit `/page/sub` without going to `/` and then click on link to go to `/page` and finally navigate to `/page/sub`, then the linking is not proper and the elements of the page will not fully load.

How can I fix this linkage issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost the same issue could be found here:

- [angular ui-router parent url set to /](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23771229/)

I've created [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/lRq7DA?p=preview) showing a working example. The trick here is to use one of the ui-router features:

- [Absolute Routes (^)](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#absolute-routes-)

As we can observe in the plunker/code snippet below, we have to adjust the state definition. We need to be able to distinguish among states just by the passed url route

1) first level, a `home` state, will be used for path '/'
2) second level, a `page` state, won't be using the parent url, but will be defined as '/page' ... starting from the root.

Therefore `ui-router` will be able to decide which state to issue. Without the [Absolute Routes (^)](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#absolute-routes-) we would need combine parent and child: '//page' would be the proper route...

```
.state('home', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'home.html'
    ...
})
// here is the change, see the ^
.state('home.page', {
    url: '^/page',
    templateUrl: 'page.html'
    ...
})
.state('home.page.sub' , {
    url: '/page/sub',
    templateUrl: 'sub.html'
    ...
})
```

And now, each state could be accessed as

```
<li><a ui-sref="home">Home</a></li>
<li><a ui-sref="home.page">- Page</a></li>
<li><a ui-sref="home.page.sub">- - Sub</a></li>
```

And its url will be:

```
#/          -- this is home
#/page      -- the page, in fact starting from root
#/page/sub
```

Working plunker: [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/lRq7DA?p=preview)

Comment: Great to see that. The `ui-router` is ... awesome ;)