# Child states not working with UI-Router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

I have the following code snippet:

```
$stateProvider.state('unlogged', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'unlogged/unlogged.html'
}).state('sign-in', {
    parent: 'unlogged',
    url: '/sign-in',
    templateUrl: 'sign-in/sign-in.html',
    controller: 'SignInCtrl'
}).state('sign-up', {
    parent: 'unlogged',
    url: '/sign-up',
    templateUrl: 'sign-up/sign-up.html',
    controller: 'SignUpCtrl'
});
```

When I go to `/sign-up`, it is not loading the parent nor the child.

My HTML when I inspect the page:  `<section ui-view="" class="ng-scope"></section>`

unlogged.html has the ui-view directive: `<div class="row" ng-class="{slide : effect}" ui-view></div>`

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [a working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/Hj8w2Z2zb0cIzHHDPSut?p=preview)

To make child state **`url`** working without parent part, we need to reset that `url` mapping with a sign **`^`**:

```
.state('sign-in', {
    parent: 'unlogged',
    url: '^/sign-in',
    ...
  })
.state('sign-up', {
    parent: 'unlogged',
    url: '^/sign-up',
    ...
  });
```

Check it in action [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Hj8w2Z2zb0cIzHHDPSut?p=preview)

Maybe also observe this:

- [angular ui-router parent url set to /](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23771229/1679310)